# Different page layouts depending on Picklist value

Tags: page-layout

I have a requirement where I have to display two different Page layouts of Contact depending on a field's Picklist Value. Contact will always be created by a System Administrator so I cant assign different page layouts to different Roles or Profiles. How to achieve the same.?
Thanks in advance

Comment: If I have understood correctly, you are looking for Record Types. Have a look at  https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=customize_recordtype.htm&language=en_US

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need to have is differenet recordtypes for different picklist values and then from Page layout assignment add page layouts to the profiles and recordtypes

Comment: Could you please help me with the same. Records will always be created with System Admin profile, so I cant add differnt page layouts to different profiles.

Comment: it doesn't matter which profile is creating the records. In that custom object definition, just create 2 recordtypes each for the selected picklist values. And then from pagelayout assignment you can assign in this way: Profile1->rectype1->pagelayout1. Recordtype here is working as a bridge between Profile and picklist selection